# update array value from firebase database

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have static tableview that return array count with this array

```
var profiles = [
    Profile(title: "Email", description: "Add Email"),
    Profile(title: "Gender", description: "Add Gender"),
    Profile(title: "Location", description: "Add Location"),
    Profile(title: "About", description: "Add About")
]
```

I want to update the description from my array from the data I get from firebase database, but when I want to update it's not showing in controller this is my code

```
fileprivate func updateUserProfile() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        guard let emailDescription = value["email"] as? String else { return }
        guard let genderDescription = value["gender"] as? String else { return}

        self.profiles[0].description = emailDescription
        self.profiles[1].description = genderDescription

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

how can I update my array from firebase database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reload data after getting updated values from Firebase. Put this in the `observeSingleEvent` completion: `self.tableView.reloadData()`